# Telerik Chart - Duplicate XCategory values in line chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, telerik, telerik-charting

Image I've got the following data:

```
X      Y
AAAAA  1
AAAAA  2
BBBBB  3
BBBBB  4
BBBBB  5
CCCCC  6
CCCCC  5
```

etc

Now I want to show them in Line Chart, so that X is X axis,  and Y is Y.
A set the XCategory to X and YValue to Y.
However, I only see the distinct values of X, like

```
AAAAA 0
BBBBB 3
CCCCC 6
```

How do I "ungroup" them?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a few options:

1. If the timestamps are (or can be made) more accurate than indicated, then use `DateTimeContinuousAxis` -- this sets the time unit ["based on the smallest difference between any two dates"](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchartview-radchartview-vs.-radchart.html).
2. If your best accuracy of the time values is as indicated (ie, to the second), then you inevitably have duplicate values for given points on the x-axis.  In that case, you'd want to use a [regular axis](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/radchartview-axes-axis.html) (not categorical), so that the points are forced to be distinct.